# Can you clip an <embed> using SVG or anything else?

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, mask, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to clip an embed element that loads native code in Chrome using NaCl. The idea is to use a mask or a clip to only view certain parts of the  element at any given time. Tried some experiments but didn't work. Did anyone else every try? Is it even possible?

Comment: How are you doing the masking/clipping?

Comment: I've tried a lot of options.

http://jsfiddle.net/5pCvB/7/

and also went through the example provided here (amongst others):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: Only firefox supports applying a URL clip-path to non-svg content. I don't know whether Chrome will do basic shape clipping of non-svg content but from the sounds of your comment it won't